# Applying progress bar to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this code where when I press `OK` button another page is loaded in the IFrame,Now I want  to add a progress bar before the next page loads in the Iframe.
This is my working code where after 2500ms the page is loaded in the Iframe

```
$('#ida').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function (){
    $("#frame1").show();
     }, 2500);
}); 

</script>

<iframe name="myframe" id="frame1" style="display:none" src="xm5.jsp" width="1300" height="1000">
</iframe></div>
```

I want to add this line of code(got it from jquery,all the css and scripts are added)

```
<div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>
```

But where should I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide **`progressbar`** div by default.

```
#progressbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Then in JS:

```
$('#ida').click(function() {
  $('#progressbar').show();   //Show when you click it
  setTimeout(function (){
    $("#frame1").show();
    $('#progressbar').hide(); //Hide when the iframe is fully loaded
     }, 2500);
});
```